# a proof of that $~C_c(X)~$ is dense in $~L^p~$ in Rudin's RCA

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm reading theorem $3.14$ in Rudin's RCA. The assertion is here:

For $1\leq p\leq \infty$, $~C_c(X)$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$. Note that $C_c(X)$ denotes the class of continuous complex functions that support is compact and the measure $\mu$ has the properties stated in Riesz-Markov-Kakutani theorem(theorem $2.14$ in RCA).

The proof is here:

Define $S$ as the class of all complex, measurable, simple functions on locally compact Hausdorff space X. If $s\in S$, and $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $g\in C_c(X)$ such that $g(x)=s(x)$ except on a set of measure $<\epsilon$, and $|g|\leq ||s||_\infty$ (Lusin's theorem).

Hence
$$||g-s||_p \leq 2\epsilon^{1/p}||s||_\infty~.$$
Since $S$ is dense in $L^p(\mu)$, this complete the proof.

Lusin's theorem says if $f$ is a complex measurable function ob $X$, $\mu(A)<\infty$, $f(x)=0$ if $x\in X-A$, and $\epsilon>0$. Then there exists a $g\in C_c(X)$ such that
$$\mu({x: f(x)\neq g(x)})<\epsilon~.$$
Furthermore, we may arrange it so that
$${\rm sup}|g|\leq {\rm sup}|f|~$$
I have a question

> How $|g|\leq ||s||_\infty~?~~ $ Justify.

Lusin's theorem merely says we can take $g$ s.t. $|g|\leq {\rm sup}|f|$.

About this question, I see [Rudin Real & Complex Analysis Thm 3.14](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249968/rudin-real-complex-analysis-thm-3-14?r=SearchResults) , but I can't get clear answer.

I think Rudin assumes ${\rm sup}|s|=||s||_\infty$, isn't true?

If it is true, certainly we can obtain the last inequality:
$$||g-s||_p= \{\int |g-s|^p d\mu\}^{1/p}\leq |g-s|\epsilon^{1/p}\leq (|g|+|s|)\epsilon^{1/p}\leq (||s||_\infty+||s||_\infty)\epsilon^{1/p}=2\epsilon^{1/p}||s||_\infty$$.

Answer (score 3):

If $s$ is a simple function, say $f= \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} c_kI_{A_k}$ then $\sup |f|=\|f\|_{\infty}$ provided none of the sets $A_k$ has measure $0$. In this proof we can assume that each $A_k$ has positive measure.

Comment: Why we can assume that each $A_k$ has positive measure? Is this related to the conditons of Lusin's theorem?

Comment: The last step in Theorem 3.14 says 'since $S$ is dense in $L^{p}$...'. Given any function in  $L^{p}$ you first approximate it by a simple function and then apply Lusin's Theorem. In this step you can omit terms where $m(A_k)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand "...then apply Lusin's theorem. In this step you can omit terms where..." Please explain the reason more rationally. I understand since $S$ is dense in $L^p$, any $f\in L^p$ can be apploximated by a sequence $\{s_n\}$ where $s_n\in L^p$ by theorem 1.17 in RCA.

Comment: Let $f \in L^{p}$ and $\epsilon >0$. Let $s=\sum c_k I_{A_k}$ be a simple function such that $\|f-s\|_p <\epsilon$. Let $s'$ be obtained from $s$ be deleting the terms in which $m(A_k)=0$. Then $s=s'$ a.e., so $\|f-s'\|_p= \|f-s\|_p<\epsilon$. For this $s$ the sup of $|s'|$ is same as $\|s'\|_{\infty}$.

Comment: Also, is there a typo in the answer? Do you want to use $s$ instead of $f$?

Comment: @epsilon-emperor Yes, I have corrected the typo. Thnaks for the comment.